# Join Two Tables where join may not exist

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm having a couple of issues writing up a join statement for Oracle. I think I want to be using a left join but I'm not 100% sure.

Here are my two tables

```
**VisibilityTable**
Industry
ProductID
Visibility
etc

**ItemTable**
ProductID
Other Info
etc
```

Here's the issue. I have ~15 Industries. Each industry wants to be able to mark a product(~15000) as Public or Private based on their preferences. I have the query working for when you want to view a specific industry's products where it's set to public or private.

The issue I'm running into is after a product is marked public or private for one industry, it's not longer appearing for the industries it has yet to be marked for. This is my query so far:

```
SELECT v.*, NVL(b.VISIBILITY,'Not Marked') Visibility 
FROM ItemTable v 
LEFT OUTER JOIN VisibilityTable b ON b.ProductID = v.ProductID
WHERE (
(v.STATUS LIKE 'Filter' or 'Filter' LIKE 'All') AND 
(v.MODEL LIKE 'Filter' or 'Filter' LIKE 'All') AND 
(v.DUTY LIKE 'Filter' or 'Filter' LIKE 'All') AND 
(v.CERTIFICATION LIKE 'Filter' or 'Filter' LIKE 'All')
)
```

This works for getting me the items that are marked as "Not Marked", "Private", "Public" but I can't get it to pull back ones that haven't been marked in the selected industry.

EDIT: Added the full where clause. This is being generated dynamically and then being passed in based on values coming from a config file.

For example, ProductID 85322 has been marked Private for Industry EPGBio but when I select Industry EPGMethane it doesn't show up as 'Not Reviewed'. It shows up as marked Private.

Comment: If 'Industry = xxx' is in your where clause, of course you're not going to get rows without the visibility entries. Edit: just saw Gordon's answer. Yes, you are defeating the purpose of your left join by filtering Industry in your where clause.

Comment: What do you mean the "ones that haven't been marked in the selected industry"?  Isn't this what *Not Marked* means?

Comment: Yes but a record that hasn't been marked doesn't have an entry in the VisibilityTable, only records that have been marked have that entry. Theoretically, the VisibilityTable will have (Number of Products * number of industries) entries.

Comment: To be honest, I don't even know if what I want is possible...

Comment: @Jabsy . . . I think I understand now what you are looking for.  See my edited answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is because you are filtering out the results where they don't appear in the where clause.

When you refer to the "b" table in the where clause, you implicitly change the `left outer join` to an `inner join`.  (Unless you happen to be doing `is null`.)

Move the conditions into the `on` clause.

I think I finally understand.  You are trying to distinguish between `b.Visibility` being NULL and the record not existing.  For this, you need a `case` statement:

```
select v.*,
       (case when b.ProductId is null then 'Not Marked at All'
             when b.Visibility is null then 'Marked as NULL'
             else b.Visibility'
        end) as Visibility
```

I changed the strings that are produced to make clear what is happening.  You can make them whatever you like.  The key is using the condition on the join key to whether the record exists, and then looking at the value, to check whether or not the value exists.

Comment: Ok, I can see how the where clause is making my join an inner join, but I'm not following how/why moving the conditions to the on clause will fix things.

My where clause has things that are specific to the product (size shape color etc) and the industry doesn't exist in the product.

Comment: @Jabsy . . . You would have to post the full query to really get help.  In all likelihood, having the filter conditions in the `where` clause is undoing the left outer join, causing the unexpected results.